# How to setup laravel framework in wampserver properly?

Tags: php, laravel

I am studying laravel now. But I am having a difficulty in installing the framework in my wampserver. I followed this instruction but I am getting an error.

***Via Download***

*Once Composer is installed, download the latest version of the Laravel framework and extract its contents into a directory on your server. Next, in the root of your Laravel application, run the php composer.phar install (or composer install) command to install all of the framework's dependencies. This process requires Git to be installed on the server to successfully complete the installation.*

*If you want to update the Laravel framework, you may issue the php composer.phar update command.*

But what I did is I extracted the laravel-master file in my www folder then I also put the composer.phar inside the laravel-master folder.

So I have a directory like this.

**C:/wamp/www/laravel-master/**

Here's my structure

```
- wamp
  - www
    - laravel
      - app (folder)
      - boostrap (folder)
      - public (folder)
      - .gitattributes
      - .gitignore
      - artisan
      - composer.json 
      - composer.phar
      - CONTRIBUTING.md
      - phpunit.xml
      - readme.md
      - server.php
      - upgrade.md
```

And in my command prompy I install the composer.phar by this way:

```
C:\wamp\www\laravel>php composer.phar install
```

But here's my error

Installing dependencies
Your requirements could not be solved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problems:
        - The requested package "laravel/framework" with constraint [> 4.0.9999999.9999999, < 4.1.9999999.9999999] could not be found.
        - Problem caused by:
                - Installation of package "laravel/laravel" with constraint == 1.0.0.0 was requested. Satisfiable by packages [laravel/laravel-1.0.0.0].
                - Package "laravel/laravel-1.0.0.0" contains the rule laravel/laravel requires laravel/framework ([> 4.0.9999999.9999999, < 4.1.9999999.9999999]). No package satisfies this dependency.
```

I also tried to install it using composer but I have an error too.

```
C:\wamp\www\laravel>composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
Installing laravel/laravel (v4.1.0)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v4.1.0)



  [RuntimeException]
  You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https



create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [package] [directory] [version]
```

When I checked the ssl in my apache and PHP it is enable. And also I check it using the phpinfo()

Please help me guys. What should I do?

Comment: Can you open your `php.ini` manually (/wamp/bin/php/{php_version}/php.ini) run a search for 'openssl' and make sure the extension is uncommented.

Comment: yes, I also uncomment the openssl there. And I also restart the wampserver.

Comment: Did you try downloading and installing [composer for windows](http://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe). During the installation wizard does it notify you that you don't have openssl?

Comment: On the command line, run `php --ri openssl` it should say it is enabled if it definitely is.

Comment: @DavidBarker - it says 'Extension 'openssl' not present.'

Comment: Ok, as I remember when I am trying to install the composer. I am running a PHP 5.3.0 and I have an error installing the composer. The reason why I am not running the latest PHP is because of my project is in older version of PHP. But now I try to install the composer again in PHP 5.4.3 and it is successfully installed. And I try to install the laravel using composer and it is now installing. But I have an error in GIT. What should I do about it? It says 'git is not recognized as internal and external command'.

Comment: if you can't see git folder when you type `echo %PATH%` in cmd, add `;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin` in `Path` system environment var, restart your cmd and type `git` again

Comment: It will be more plaisant for you to use Git Bash.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

**Installing Laravel 4 on WAMP**

## 1. Enable OpenSSL

OpenSSL must be enabled in the PHP configuration.

Edit `php.ini` in your WAMP’s PHP folder, e.g.:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\{Your.PHP.Version}\
```

where `{Your.PHP.Version}` is something like `php5.4.12`.

## Note:

You should not edit the `php.ini` inside

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\{Your.Apache.Version}\bin
```

where `{Your.Apache.Version}` is something like `Apache2.4.4`, because that is not the file that Composer uses.

Find the following line and remove its preceding semicolon (if there is one) and save the file. So change

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

## 2. Install Composer

Now we need to install Composer. This is a dependency manager that will download the latest release of Laravel and specific versions of Laravel’s dependencies, such as Doctrine and Symfony.

2.1. Download the Composer Windows installer from

```
https://getcomposer.org/download/
```

2.2. Run the installer.

2.3. When it asks for the location of `php.exe`, point it to the executable in your WAMP’s PHP folder, e.g.:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\{Your.PHP.Version}\
```

2.4. Finish the installation.

2.5. Open a command-line interface (cmd) and type:

```
composer
```

It should return a list of options. If you get an error, restart your computer and try again.

Composer has now been installed and added to your PATH environment variable. This means you can run it from any directory using the command-line interface.

## 3.Install Laravel

Now that Composer has been installed, Composer can download and install Laravel on your system.

3.1. Open a command-line interface (cmd).

3.2. Go to the directory in which you want to install Laravel. This is usually your development directory. In this tutorial, we’ll use `C:\wamp\www\laravel`

3.3. Instruct Composer to install Laravel into a project directory. We use project name `myproject`.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel myproject --prefer-dist
```

## Note:

**This will install Laravel in a subdirectory named `myproject` under current working directory.**

Now your project has a running directory like

```
C:\wamp\www\laravel\myproject\public\
```

Please check as accepted answer and upvote.

Comment: Even after a year, yes, this helped me a lot with a laravel 5 installation

Comment: Nice one, appreciated

Answer (score 9):

I am using this procedure to set up laravel to wamp server and it work perfectly

```
1.you have to put laravel in  C:\wamp\www folder

2.then u have to go application/config ....open application.php and change url='';

3.change key='K3u4UsHKh7AjSitP9VLTMtbd1mjvdzmQ'

4.then u have to go int C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\conf\extra  folder then
  open <<=== httpd-vhosts.conf ===>> file and paste below this line into that folder

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/laravel/public
    ServerName xxxxx.dev
</VirtualHost>


5.then go   C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc  folder and open <<=== hosts ===>> file then paste
 127.0.0.1       xxxxx.dev

6.then go C:\wamp\www\laravel\public folder ...and then open a.htaccess ..then paste 
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
7.Then u have to go >> C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf <<  this directory & open httpd.conf & comment out this line

# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

8.then go wamp server .....start it ..and click rewrite mode in apache->apache module..then restart wamp server

9.then go ur browser and write xxxxx.dev/docs  ...
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: very useful answer.But to note you can use :
http://localhost/add_vhost.php
which adds the dns automatically in the wamp and windows hosts.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to enable openssl and curl in php to run composer properly you must do this in both the apache bin and the php bin in wamp. Apache uses it's own php.ini when WAMP server is running, however anytime you run PHP from the command line it runs using the wamp/bin/php version so edit both these files to ensure it runs properly:
`/wamp/bin/apache/ApacheX.X.X/bin/php.ini` and `/wamp/bin/php/phpX.X.X/php.ini`

look for extension=php_openssl.dll ~line 970 and extension=php_curl.dll ~line 952

After that is done you should set up a virtualhost by following these steps: http://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp

In new versions of WAMP you can copy the vhosts.conf into the wamp/vhosts dir to create separate vhosts file for each vhost you set up.

Make sure you point the documentroot to your /public dir of where your laravel project will be (it does not need to be in wamp/www it can be installed in wamp/myproject if you want so long as the webroot points to wamp/myproject/public.

It's best to download the windows installer and install composer globally.  Once it is installed simply use Laravel's quick install method by typing `composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist`

If you are running PHP 5.4 in your wamp stack you can simply use the CLI to go to the root of your laravel install and type `php artisan serve` which will fire up PHP's built in webserver on port 8000.  You can access your laravel project by going to localhost:8000 or fire up wamp and visit the vhost domain you setup in the steps above.

If all goes well you should get the "You have arrived!" welcome screen.