# Can't route in fresh laravel 5.6 installation

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes, composer-php, laravel-5.6

Today I started a fresh laravel installation through composer with this piece of code(just as always):

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel new_proj
```

after the installation the welcome page starts successfully with the laravel logo at the center.
The problem is I can't route a new url for example when I type the following code in the `route\web.php`, I get the error **"Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found"**

```
Route::get('foo', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

another problem is that when I turn on the debug mode in the `config\app.php` I still get no detailed error to fix the problem.

for possible answers I should say using port:8000 hasn't fix my problem and by the way ... `php artisan serve` doesn't work too and get this error : **Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.** .... note that I have checked whether if another service is using this port only to find that no service is using it

I have always used this routine to install laravel and it has worked perfectly but with the new version (5.6) it seems that it doesn't work or I am doing sth wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your `route/web.php` file, you need to restart your laravel instance. Do you check, if your URL is correct (to enter your `foo` page)?

If `php artisan serve` doesn't work, try to check your firewall or change the port by using `php artisan serve --port=YOUR-NEW-PORT` (replace `YOUR-NEW-PORT` with another port than 8000).

Comment: artisan server now works with new port, also the routed url .......... but I wonder why it doesn't work with my wamp server

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984148/how-to-setup-laravel-framework-in-wampserver-properly

Comment: Actually my other previous laravel projects are working correctly with my wamp server right now ..... only the new installed ones are not working and I can't figure out why .......
The front welcome page also loads up perfect but I can't route new url. (only in wamp ...... in other ports other that 8000 and 3306 it works correct)

Comment: @MohamadPishdad have you found a fix to this as routes does not work on my wamp but works on php artisan serve.

Comment: @Lordcash not quite sure ,,, but I think updating composer kinda fixed it although I haven't retest it so much

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your `.env` file was created,
if not proceed to create it then.
Generate an application encryption key for your app with `php artisan key:generate`