# Laravel project not running because of Avast AntiVirus

Tags: php, laravel, project

I read that if you get a specific error that the server.php is missing, that Avast AntiVirus removes it whenever you run `php artisan serve`. I looked it up on google on how to add an exception. Found out how to do it and added an exception like this `C:\wamp\www\*`. It didn't work so i shut down Avast entirely. Does anyone know what i did wrong?

Comment: My guess would be installing AVAST was your first mistake :)

Comment: Are you putting your site code in the `\wamp\www` folder?

Comment: It looks like your working with WAMP. That's a webserver so you do not need php artisan serve. Just configure your Apache file to serve the application, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22980932/9113589